# Python - Get All the couple combinations from a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like to get all the possible couples of elements from a list like the following :

```
L = [1, 2, 4, 5]
--> couples = [(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 5), (4, 5)]
```

I do not want symetric couples like `(1, 2), (2, 1)` and I do not want couples with same numbers either like `(1, 1)`

If you guys could tell me the best way to do it I would be super glad !

Comment: Have a look at the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html).

Comment: In particular combinations ...

Answer (score -1):

A simple way of getting combinations

```
 def getPairs(inList):
    outList = []

    for i in range(len(inList)):
        item = inList[0]
        inList = inList[1:]
        for j in inList:
            outList.append((item, j))

    return outList
```